# Filled and hollow shapes where the fill color = the line color

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to convey three types of information in a dot-plot. I can use color, shape and fill (my actual data has too many points to use size effectively). But it would look best if the fill color was the same as the outline color.

The closest I can get is this:

```
data(mtcars)
p <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=mpg,y=wt))+
  geom_point(aes(color=factor(cyl),shape=factor(gear),fill=factor(vs)))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("black",NA))+scale_shape_manual(values=c(21,22,23))
```

[image]

which fills black into all outline colors, ugly. Any ideas on how to fill the red points with red and the blue points with blue?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Introduce `NA`, and map those to the `NA` color with `scale_fill_discrete`:

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=mpg,y=wt)) +
  geom_point(size=10,
    aes(
      color=factor(cyl), 
      shape=factor(gear), 
      fill=factor(ifelse(vs, NA, cyl))            # <---- NOTE THIS
  ) ) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(21,22,23)) +
  scale_fill_discrete(na.value=NA, guide="none")  # <---- NOTE THIS
```

Produces:

[image]

---

EDIT: To address Mr Flick, we can cheat and add layers / alpha.  Note we need to add a layer because as far as I know there is no way to control alpha independently for color and fill:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=mpg,y=wt, color=factor(cyl), shape=factor(gear))) +
  geom_point(size=10, aes(fill=factor(cyl), alpha=as.character(vs))) +
  geom_point(size=10) +      
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(21,22,23)) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values=c("1"=0, "0"=1))
```

[image]

Comment: Clever. But it's not easy to add a legend for the `vs` value indicating which ones are filled and which ones are empty, is it? Right now it's not clear what's the difference between the filled and empty ones.

Comment: Another clever solution/workaround. I regret I have but one up vote to give.

Comment: Both solutions are incredibly clever. Thanks! I must admit that it is very hard to understand how they work. In the second solution, with the scale, why do the aesthetics have to be split between the ggplot call and the geom_point() call? And why do the open shapes vanish without the second geom_point(size=10)?

Comment: My bad, answering my own question. The main call to ggplot is given all the aesthetics except the tough one, "fill."  The first layer, created by geom_point makes the filled points, but the open points are drawn as invisible with alpha=0. The second layer, created by the second call to geom_point, draws only hollow shapes, including re-outlining the filled shapes.  Even cooler, layers are added sequentially so if the two geom_point() calls are reversed, the solids cover the open shapes.

Comment: @PeterK, exactly.  Also, the first one works because we set the fill value of every `vs==1` point to `NA`.  This results in a dark gray color, but if we manually specify that the `NA` color should be `NA` instead of the default, then the "color" becomes transparent (that is how `NA` is interpreted).

Comment: Thanks! Just want to share that picking `shape = 21` **other than** the default 19 (solid disc) is also necessary since `shape = 19` does not support the `fill` option.