# ggplot: how to assign both color and shape for one factor, and also shape for another factor?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I must code factor `age` with both `color` and `shape`. I know how to do that (see the plot and data/code below).

In addition, I also have to code factor `day` with `shape`.

Is it somehow possible to assign specified different shapes to two different factors?

Below is the legend I would love to achieve (I made an example in power point).
The plot is not quite right, as only factor age is coded with color and shape.

[image]

```
df = data.frame(test = c(1,2,3, 1,2,3, 1,2,3,  1,2,3, 1,2,3, 1,2,3),
                age = c(1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3,3,   1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3,3),
                day = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
                result = c(1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,0, 2,2,0,1,2,1,2,1,0))

df$test <- factor((df$test))
df$age <- factor((df$age))
df$day <- factor((df$day))

windows(width=4, height=3 )

df %>%
  ggplot( aes(x=test, y=result)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=age, shape=age, group=age), 
             position=position_jitterdodge(dodge.width=0.8,jitter.height=0.2, jitter.width=0), 
             size=2, stroke=0.8)  +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(16, 15, 17), name="", labels=c("young","older","the oldest")) +
  scale_color_manual(name="", labels=c("young","older","the oldest"), values=c('#009E73','#56B4E9','#D55E00')) +
  
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        legend.position=c(), legend.text=element_text(size=10, face="bold"), legend.title=element_text(size=10),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank() ,
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank() ,
        plot.title = element_text(size=10, face = "bold"), axis.title=element_text(size=11),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=9, angle = 45), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=9, angle = 90),
        plot.margin = unit(c(0.5,0.2,0,0), "cm")) +
  
  labs(title= "", x = "",y = "Test result") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,1,2), labels=c('good','better','the best')) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=c(0.5,1.5,2.5),color="grey90")+
  geom_hline(yintercept=-0.5, color="grey90")+
  expand_limits(x=3.9, y=c(0,2.35)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("1", "2", "3"),labels = c("test a", "test b", "test c")) + 
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

Comment: This is clever work around: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632242/filled-and-hollow-shapes-where-the-fill-color-the-line-color The idea is use the "hollow" shapes and then fill them based on day. (i.e. `fill=factor(ifelse(day==1, NA, age)))`) I'm not sure how you'd get the specific legend you want though.

Comment: I am trying to make this work at least for the data points... Maybe I can make a legend in power point. I added this: ```geom_point(aes(color=age, shape=age, group=age, fill=factor(ifelse(day==1, NA, age))), ```. And changed the shapes: ```scale_shape_manual(values=c(1, 0, 2),``` And tried various ```scale_fill_discrete```, ```scale_fill_manual``` , but still cannot get the shapes to be filled in correctly.

Comment: I was misleading in my comment, rather than "hallow" shapes, we want shapes 21 through 26. These apparently accept distinct fill and color. So values == c(22, 21, 24)` or something like that; but @tjebo has a more complete answer.

Comment: @AriAnisfeld no need to delete your answer! It's a great start, and maybe more what the OP wants. Who knows? Kindly consider undeleting it - it might help others in the future with similar questions

Comment: Yes, I do agree - I would love to see the other answer. I just had a chance to briefly glance at it... I am so grateful for everyone here. Perhaps all answers can be somehow useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use shapes on an interaction between age and day, and use color only one age. Then remove the color legend and color the shape legend manually with `override.aes`.

This comes close to what you want - labels can be changes, I've defined them when creating the factors.

**how to make fancy legends**

However, you want a quite fancy legend, so the easiest would be to build the legend yourself as a separate plot and combine to the main panel. ("Fake legend"). This requires some semi-hardcoding, but you're not shy to do this anyways given the manual definition of your shapes. See Part Two how to do this.

**Part one**

```r
library(ggplot2)
df = data.frame(test = c(1,2,3, 1,2,3, 1,2,3,  1,2,3, 1,2,3, 1,2,3),
                age = c(1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3,3,   1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3,3),
                day = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
                result = c(1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,0, 2,2,0,1,2,1,2,1,0))

df$test <- factor(df$test)
## note I'm changing this here already!! If you udnergo the effor tof changing to
## factor, define levels and labels here
df$age <- factor(df$age, labels = c("young", "older", "the oldest"))
df$day <- factor(df$day, labels = paste("Day", 1:2))

ggplot(df, aes(x=test, y=result)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(color=age, shape=interaction(day, age)),
              width = .1, height = .1) +
  ## you won't get around manually defining the shapes
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(0, 15, 1, 16, 2, 17)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('#009E73','#56B4E9','#D55E00')) +
  guides(color = "none", 
         shape = guide_legend(
          override.aes = list(color = rep(c('#009E73','#56B4E9','#D55E00'), each = 2)),
          ncol = 3))
```

[image]

**Part two** - the fake legend

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(patchwork)

## df and factor creation as above !!!

p_panel <- 
ggplot(df, aes(x=test, y=result)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(color=age, shape=interaction(day, age)),
              width = .1, height = .1) +
  ## you won't get around manually defining the shapes
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(0, 15, 1, 16, 2, 17)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('#009E73','#56B4E9','#D55E00')) +
  ## for this solution, I'm removing the legend entirely
  theme(legend.position = "none") 

## make the data frame for the fake legend
## the y coordinates should be defined relative to the y values in your panel
y_coord <- c(.9, 1.1)
df_legend <- df %>% distinct(day, age) %>% 
  mutate(x = rep(1:3,2), y = rep(y_coord,each = 3))

## The legend plot is basically the same as the main plot, but without legend -
## because it IS the legend ... ;)
lab_size = 10*5/14
p_leg <- 
  ggplot(df_legend, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=age, shape=interaction(day, age))) +
  ## I'm annotating in separate layers because it keeps it clearer (for me)
  annotate(geom = "text", x = unique(df_legend$x), y = max(y_coord)+.1, 
           size = lab_size, angle = 45, hjust = 0,
           label = c("young", "older", "the oldest")) +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = max(df_legend$x)+.2, y = y_coord, 
           label = paste("Day", 1:2), size = lab_size, hjust = 0) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(0, 15, 1, 16, 2, 17)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('#009E73','#56B4E9','#D55E00')) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        plot.margin = margin(r = .3,unit = "in")) +
  ## you need to turn clipping off and define the same y limits as your panel
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off", ylim = range(df$result))

## now combine them
p_panel + p_leg +
  plot_layout(widths = c(1,.2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

So again following: [Filled and hollow shapes where the fill color = the line color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632242/filled-and-hollow-shapes-where-the-fill-color-the-line-color) the following code provides the goods without giving you the legend.

```
df %>%
  ggplot( aes(x=test, y=result)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=age, 
                 shape=age, 
                 group=age,
                 fill=factor(ifelse(day==1, NA, age))), # STEP 1
             position=position_jitterdodge(dodge.width=0.8,jitter.height=0.2, jitter.width=0), 
             size=2, stroke=0.8)  +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(22,21,24), name="", labels=c("young","older","the oldest")) +
  scale_color_manual(name="", labels=c("young","older","the oldest"), values=c('#009E73','#56B4E9','#D55E00')) +
  scale_fill_manual(name="",
                      labels=c("young","older","the oldest"), 
                      values=c('#009E73','#56B4E9','#D55E00'), 
                      na.value=NA, guide="none") # STEP 2
```

I was misleading in my comment, rather than "hallow" shapes, we want shapes 21 through 26. These apparently accept distinct `fill` and `color`.